# multiple language selection options inside an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've found some similar questions. But neither the questions, nor the answers clarified my problem.

I want to implement an option from which the user can select a language of his/her choice inside an iPhone application. (Localization is not the stuff I need) Upon selection of a language, the app should be translated to the selected language.

How can this be implemented ?

I want the users to select the language, not to use the system language through localization.

Comment: have  a look @ this http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/11/localizing-iphone-apps.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html

Comment: what is so hard of it? you create a database with the possible languages, you store the selected languages and you read all the text for the UI from your database. the `KVC` can help you to manage it with `.plist` files, `NSDictionary` object, etc... is it a real question really? :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create language files (strings/xml/plist ... depend on you)
Second, make a screen for user choosing language, save chosen language information to NSUserDefaults.

Finally, write a method for checking saved language in NSUserDefault and reading strings/xml/plist.

Google more, do those steps, and post your problems that you meet when working here, i will help in detail :)

Comment: Good, saved me writing the same thing xD